# What nontrivial operations exhibit $\text{op}(f(x)) + \text{op}(f(x+1)) = \text{op}(f(x) + f(x+1))$?

Tags: functions, intuition

What *nontrivial* operations exhibit $\text{op}(f(x)) + \text{op}(f(x+1)) = \text{op}(f(x) + f(x+1))$?

For example, I know that summation, integration, and their inverses all exhibit this property.  To further illustrate this, we can take summation:

$$\sum_x{f(x)} + \sum_x{f(x+1)} = \sum_x{(f(x) + f(x+1))}$$

Or integration:

$$\int{f(x)dx} + \int{f(x+1)dx} = \int{(f(x) + f(x+1))dx}$$

**So my question is: What other operations/functions have this property?**  Can we somehow classify them all?  **Also, does this property have a name?**

Comment: Apparently these are classified as additive functions.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function  I just wonder if there are others that aren't listed on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: We can add rings and fields to the list...

Comment: Well, summation, integration, differentiation, *etc.* are all linear, so they satisfy ${\rm op}(a) + {\rm op}(b) = {\rm op}(a + b)$ for any $a$ and $b$. Do you have an example in mind that's not linear but still satisfies the identity when $a=f(x), b=f(x+1)$?

Comment: @Rahul:  Hmm...  I can't seem to find one, but maybe I'm missing the obvious.  I'd be grateful if you could help me find more!

Answer (score 1):

This' neat!

These types of operations are typically found under the notions of *homomorphism*, ie ``structure preserving mapping''.

More precisely, suppose we have a set $S$ and a binary operation on it $\oplus:S \times S \to S$, then we call $(S,\oplus)$ a *magma*.
(If this operation has a unit and is invertible we obtain the notion of *group*.)

Now suppose we have two magmas $(S,\oplus_S)$ and $(T,\oplus_T)$ then a structure-preserving mapping ---or `magma homomorphism'--- would be a map $$h : S \to T$$
such that $$h(a \oplus_S b)=h(a) \oplus_T h(b), \;\;\;\text{for any $a,b$ in $S$ }$$

In particular, if we take $h,a,b$ to be $op, f(x), f(x+1)$, respectively, then we obtain your specific instance :)

Another example is to consider the magmas $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R},\times)$, then the exponential operation $r \mapsto \exp(r)$ is a homomorphism since $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a) \times \exp(b)$.

Hope this helps!